# Matlab VS Python - eig(A,B) VS sc.linalg.eig(A,B)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, eigenvalue

I have the following matrices sigma and sigmad:

sigma:

```
    1.9958   0.7250
    0.7250   1.3167
```

sigmad:

```
    4.8889   1.1944
    1.1944   4.2361
```

If I try to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem in python I obtain:

```
    d,V = sc.linalg.eig(matrix(sigmad),matrix(sigma))
```

V:

```
    -1     -0.5614
    -0.4352    1
```

If I try to solve the g. e. problem in matlab I obtain:

```
    [V,d]=eig(sigmad,sigma)
```

V:

```
    -0.5897    -0.5278
    -0.2564    0.9400
```

But the d's do coincide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any (nonzero) scalar multiple of an eigenvector will also be an eigenvector; only the direction is meaningful, not the overall normalization.  Different routines use different conventions -- often you'll see the magnitude set to 1, or the maximum value set to 1 or -1 -- and some routines don't even bother being internally consistent for performance reasons.  Your two different results are multiples of each other:

```
In [227]: sc = array([[-1., -0.5614], [-0.4352,  1.    ]])

In [228]: ml = array([[-.5897, -0.5278], [-0.2564, 0.94]])

In [229]: sc/ml
Out[229]: 
array([[ 1.69577751,  1.06366048],
       [ 1.69734789,  1.06382979]])
```

and so they're actually the same eigenvectors.  Think of the matrix as an operator which changes a vector: the eigenvectors are the special directions where a vector pointing that way won't be twisted by the matrix, and the eigenvalues are the factors measuring how much the matrix expands or contracts the vector.