# Eigen decomposition of two square matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

In matlab we have option to find eigen decomposition of two matrix, no matter there product is symmetric or non symmetric such as

```
A = [1 3; 4 9];
B = [4 7; 9 16];
[Vec,Val]=eig(A,B)
```

Vectors are

```
`[-1,-1;0.54,0.85]`
```

and value are

```
[-3.79,0;0,0.79]
```

I have checked in python [numpy.linalg](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvals.html) but there is no such option. All of the eig variation accept only one parameters. Is there way to deal with this in python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab VS Python - eig(A,B) VS sc.linalg.eig(A,B)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691981/matlab-vs-python-eiga-b-vs-sc-linalg-eiga-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scipy.linalg.eig](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html):

```
from scipy import linalg
linalg.eig(A, B)
```

where `A = [[1,3],[4,9]]` and `B = [[4,7], [9,16]]` are your two matrices.